# Why the code in a pre tag which is inside a table cell look terrible?

Tags: html, code-snippets, pre

I have tried to use html to make my own quick reference to different programming language, in the reference I tried to put the code snippet inside a pre tag which is inside a cell tag.

**First, html like this, and the codes look terrible**

```
                <td>
                    <pre><code>if (..){

                    } else {

                    }</code></pre>
                </td>
```

**Then, i have fixed the problem by removing all the indent in `pre` tag**

```
                    <td>
<pre><code>if (..) {

} else {

}</code></pre>
                    </td>
```

This picture shows the difference, the first cell is written the beautiful indent html, while the others cell are written by ugly indent html. I don't understand the reason, and if there any ways to fix the problem ?
[image: example]

Comment: this is one of the characteristics of <pre>, you cannot change it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pre` element preserves whitespace (including spaces and line breaks) exactly as written in the HTML source. This completely explains what happens. In your first code snippet, e.g. the third line has a large number of spaces before the text `} else {`, and those spaces will be preserved. The first line in that `pre` element has no leading spaces, since the line starts after the start tag `<pre>`.